# How can I unit test my react component prop API

Tags: reactjs

I have a component with a list of props and I want to ensure that unit test catches props that are removed by accident without following a process of deprecation.

Let's say designer decides to remove a prop called showAll.  I want my unit test to capture the fact that the prop was removed.  Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 1):

If props are important to your web app I would strongly suggest using prop-types from react.

Basically how you could use this to enforce behaviour would be something like this:

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class Greeting extends React.Component { // your component would be here
    render() {
        return (
            <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>
        );
    }
}

Greeting.propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string.required
};
```

I think you can then access the proptypes for this component by using `Greeting.propTypes`

Therefore I could see a test that implements something similar to the following logic working:

- test to see if your component includes the prop -> this indicates it's at least usable and possibly deprecated, but not removed completely

This test would pass if the programmer deprecated the prop by making it no longer required, but it wouldn't pass if the programmer completely removed it.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I found something interesting called check-prop-types.  I did a script to verify the props and compare to a saved file.  In a spec.js file I validate the props and if anything has changed it will fail.